# Understanding the Wordpress vulnerability

Tags: php, security, wordpress

A vulnerability has recently been disclosed that affects WordPress 2.8.3 and allows the admin user to be locked out of their account by changing the password.

[This post](http://lists.grok.org.uk/pipermail/full-disclosure/2009-August/070137.html) on Full Disclosure details the flaw, and includes relevant code snippets. The post mentions that *'You can abuse the password reset function, and bypass the first step and then reset the admin password by submiting an array to the $key variable.'*

I'd be interested in someone familiar with PHP explaining the bug in more detail.

Those affected should [update](http://wordpress.org/development/2009/08/2-8-4-security-release/) to a new 2.8.4 release which apparently fixes the flaw.

```
wp-login.php:
...[snip]....
line 186:
function reset_password($key) {
    global $wpdb;

    $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $key);

    if ( empty( $key ) )
        return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

    $user = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE
user_activation_key = %s", $key));
    if ( empty( $user ) )
        return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));
...[snip]....
line 276:
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'login';
$errors = new WP_Error();

if ( isset($_GET['key']) )
    $action = 'resetpass';

// validate action so as to default to the login screen
if ( !in_array($action, array('logout', 'lostpassword', 'retrievepassword',
'resetpass', 'rp', 'register', 'login')) && false ===
has_filter('login_form_' . $action) )
    $action = 'login';
...[snip]....

line 370:

break;

case 'resetpass' :
case 'rp' :
    $errors = reset_password($_GET['key']);

    if ( ! is_wp_error($errors) ) {
        wp_redirect('wp-login.php?checkemail=newpass');
        exit();
    }

    wp_redirect('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&error=invalidkey');
    exit();

break;
...[snip ]...
```

Comment: Thank you for accidentally alerting me to update my word press installs. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So $key is an array in the querystring with a single empty string ['']

> `http://DOMAIN_NAME.TLD/wp-login.php?action=rp&key[]=`

reset_password gets called with an array, and then preg_replace gets called:

```
 //$key = ['']
 $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $key);
 //$key = [''] still
```

because [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) accepts either a string or an array of strings.  It regex replaces nothing and returns the same array.  $key is not empty (it's an array of an empty string) so this happens:

```
 $user = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users 
      WHERE user_activation_key = %s", $key));
```

Now from here, I need to go read the wordpress source for how prepare behaves...

**More:**

So prepare calls [vsprintf](https://www.php.net/vsprintf) which produces an empty string

```
$a = array('');
$b = array($a);
vsprintf("%s", $b);
//Does not produce anything
```

So the SQL is:

> SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_activation_key = ''

Which will *apparently* match the admin user (and all users without activation_keys I suppose).

And that's how.

Comment: an empty array will return true for an empty() check, but by passing key[]= you get an array with an empty string as its only element.
vpsprintf() returns a value, rather than outputting one so your sample code isn't really telling anything. In both cases, your reasoning is sound and the end result is the same.

Comment: It's worth noting this exploit doesn't affect older Wordpress installs, and only became viable with a recent [change](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/10721) to `prepare`

Answer (score 0):

I have a related question on [how to patch this vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372632/patch-for-wordpress-remote-admin-reset-password-vulnerability) - line 190 on the wp-login.php should now look like this;

```
if ( empty( $key ) || is_array( $key ) )
```